# Can't understand with Fragment Manager

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I'm trying to add a fragment using SupportFragmentManager, but the add function is highlighted in red. This code worked in another project. Probably something I don't understand. The whole problem is visible in the picture.

Something is wrong with "add"

Error: None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.

```
package com.example.homework4_task1.presentation.main

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.core.view.WindowCompat
import androidx.fragment.app.commit
import androidx.fragment.app.add
import com.example.homework4_task1.R
import com.example.homework4_task1.presentation.main.fragments.MainFragment

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        fitContentViewToInsets()

        supportFragmentManager.commit {
            add<MainFragment> { 
                R.id.container
            }
        }
    }

    private fun fitContentViewToInsets() {
        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
    }

}
```

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.5.5'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

[something wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxVOQ.png)

Comment: Please copy-paste your code instead of take a screenshot of it

Comment: Please don't use screenshots for code but instead format it using markdown.  And you have to tell us what the lining says about the error.

Comment: Sorry, added code and error-message

Comment: Do you have a dependency on `fragment-ktx` in your build.gradle file? Please include your `dependencies` block

Comment: Added dependencies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is you are using a lambda at the end; the only similarity I can find is:

```
add<MainFragment>(R.id.container)
```

Which is in fact an extension and you have to import

```
import androidx.fragment.app.add
```

I think the problem is the lambda because that would mean you are passing a function that returns an id (`Int` `@ResId`). But the available methods will always require a parameter as an `id` to know where to attach the fragment.